# React/JS, useState - Why will Button change text only twice when taking text out of Array with 10 elements?

Tags: reactjs, variables, storage, use-state

I want to have a Button that changes the text ten times.

- So I made an array `clickArray`with 10 strings, and a counter `let count = 0`.
- Made a function `setCount()`with an if else that ticks up the counter and turns back to zero after 10.

```
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Click")

let count = 0

const setCount = () => {
    if (count < clickArr.length) {
      count ++
    } else {
      count = 0 
    }
  }

 const handleClick = () => {
    setButtonText(clickArr[count])
    setCount()
  }



// in return():
<div className="button" onClick={handleClick}>{buttonText}</div>
```

--> No error is thrown, but the counter behaves weird. Console logging everything brings no clarity.

- First click: Button changes text from default text "Click" to `clickArr[0]` as it should. setCount ticks count to 1
- Second click: Nothing happens.
- Third click: Counter ticks to 3
- Fourth click: Counter ticks to 1

`console.log(setCount())` is "undefined"

I think i dont store `count` correctly, but thats just a guess.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does `setCount` do ?

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  Currently you are referring to functionality which isn't included in the code shown.

Comment: Also i just noticed the `let count = 0`. If you do not persist this value in state, it will be reset in each render.

Comment: Can you share a online demo of this using stackblitz or similar?

Comment: I updated the code,
it is okay for now it count updates each render.

Comment: @Geza We are completely out of clue. Can you share a demo with any online link of your issue or have you solved it?

Comment: What is `clickArr` anyway?

Comment: `count` always starts at `0` every time the component renders. Also, `setCount` does not return a value, and thus doing a console log of the call will always show `undefined`.

Comment: I solved it with the help of AKX
Thanks for the help and all the fast feedback. I love stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my crystal ball is correct, you want a component where a button's text is picked from an array on each click of the button.

If so, then you'll want to just derive the button text based on the array (which could be state if required) and the click number state atom.

- The `setCount` invocation here is [using the functional update form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of `setState`, so it doesn't need to read the `count` state itself (and is safe from possible stale state closure problems).
- I'm using the modulus operator `%` so the counting operation does not need to even know how many texts there are.

```
const clickArr = ["Click", "Clack", "Bleep", "Bloop"];

function Component() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const buttonText = clickArr[count % clickArr.length];
  const handleClick = () => setCount((c) => c + 1);
  return (
    <div className="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      {buttonText}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! it is working as I wanted it!